# Vector equation for line that passes through a point and is parallel to another vector

Tags: vectors

Write a vector equation of the line that passes through point P and is parallel to vector a

Point $P=(-2,1)$
Vector $a=(3,-4)$

Can someone just explain this to me? I know how to write vector equations but not with only one point and when I have to make it parallel to something else!

Comment: What kind of vector equations do you know how to write?

Comment: I know how to write 4 different kinds but my preferred form is <x,y> = <r,s> + t<a,b>

Comment: Would you know how to write the equation for the line that's parallel to (pointing in the same direction as) $(3, -4)$? If so, you could just translate it by the vector $(-2, 1)$.

Comment: It sounds like you know how find the vector equation of the line when given some other information. What information?

Comment: To do that equation I need two points.

Comment: Use the two points $(0, 0)$ and $(3, -4)$ to find a line parallel to the one you're looking for. Then translate by the vector $(-2, 1)$.

Comment: or simply add $\ bf a$ to $\bf P$ to find the 2nd point.

Answer (score 0):

so the general solution here would be $r(t) = (a,b) + t(c,d)$, or $x = a + ct$, $y = b + dt$.  In your case you have the equation $r(t) = (-2,1) + t(3,-4)$.  Because $(-2,1)$ is the point you want to go through, that'll be your point, and t is multiplied by the vector $(3,-4)$ because that's the vector you want yours to be parallel to.  The equation I gave you for $r(t)$ above should be acceptable, but it can also be $x = -2 + 3t$, $y = 1 - 4t$.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Choose between the following formulations:

- $\boldsymbol{r} = \boldsymbol{P} + t \boldsymbol{a}$
- $ \frac{x - \boldsymbol{P}_x}{\boldsymbol{a}_x}=\frac{y - \boldsymbol{P}_y}{\boldsymbol{a}_y} = const. $
- $ (-\boldsymbol{a}_y) x + ( \boldsymbol{a}_x) y + (\boldsymbol{a}_y \boldsymbol{P}_x - \boldsymbol{a}_x \boldsymbol{P}_y) = 0$

All of them are equations of a line on a plane.

Answer (score 0):

Pick an arbitrary point $Q=(x,y)$ in the plane (different from $P$). This **point** is in the line you want if the **vector** $Q-P = (x+2, y-1)$ is parallel to the vector $a$. This gives us $(x+2, y-1) = t (3,-4)$ for some $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

Drawing this picture may clarify the relation between the geometric and analytic definitions.